# How to avoid eagerloading problem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Here is my code below.

Client has many events with foreign key client_id in 'events' table

`has_many :events`

In console

```
clients = Client.where(id: [110,112,113,115]).includes(:events)
=>  Client Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`id` IN (110, 112, 113, 115)
    Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`client_id` IN (110, 112, 113, 115)
```

But when run following,

```
clients.each { |cr| cr.events.count }
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`client_id` = 110
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`client_id` = 112
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`client_id` = 113
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`client_id` = 115
```

I am getting N+1 queries, I am missing something.

### Update

From answer provided I got clue, I wanted ids of events so I was trying as,

```
clients.each { |cr| cr.events.ids }
clients.each { |cr| cr.events.pluck(:id) }
```

So N+1 queries got fired, then I worked out with following and solved,

```
clients.each { |cr| cr.events.map(&:id) }
```

I treated Relation as Array and used `map` instead of `ids` or `pluck` and solved, no N+1 query got fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.count` in case of ActiveRecord Relation will simply run the query. If you change it to `.size`, the length of array of eager-loaded items will be checked, which is what you're after.

Comment: This helped me to find answer, check update in question.

Comment: @ray yeah, `pluck` is also a method that would cause ActiveRecord to fire a query, while `map` works on provided array and won't need anything from the DB. If you asked about pluck straight away, I'd've helped more ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to fetch event ids use join with pluck

```
event_ids = Client.where(id: [110,112,113,115]).joins(:events).pluck('events.id')
```

Comment: helped this too.

Comment: No need for joins, you could filter events by `client_id`.